# I have an error in the code and the error is: (IntelliSense: object of abstract class type "HourlyWorker" is not allowed: )

Tags: c++

Employee class is abstract class because it contains two virtual function.
PieceWorker class is a concrete class and inherits Employee class publicly.
HourlyWorker class is a concrete class and inherits Employee class publicly.

The compiler is letting me do this:
Employee* ptr1;
ptr1 = new PieceWorker(wage,pieces);

But the compiler is not letting me do the following in the same code:
Employee* ptr2;
ptr2 = new HourlyWorker(3.3, 6.6);

HERE IS THE CODE FOR REFERENCE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Employee
{
    char name[30];
    char type[30];
public:
    void setName() {cin.getline(name,30);}
    void setType() {cin.getline(type,30);}
    virtual void calculate() = 0;//pure virtual function
    virtual void getWage() = 0;//pure virtual function
    void getName() {
        int index =0;
        do
        {
            cout << name[index] ;
            index++;
        }
        while (name[index]!='\0') ;
        cout << endl ;
    }
    void getType() {
            int index =0;
        do
        {
            cout << type[index] ;
            index++;
        }
        while (type[index]!='\0') ;
        cout << endl ;
    }
};
class PieceWorker: public Employee
{
    float wage, totalPay;
    int pieces;
public:
    PieceWorker() {}
    PieceWorker(float wage, int pieces) {
        this->wage = wage ;
        this->pieces = pieces ;
    }
    void calculate() {
        totalPay = wage * pieces;
    }
    void getWage()
    {
        cout << "The total Earning is: " << totalPay << endl ;
    }
};
class HourlyWorker: public Employee
{
    float wage, hours, totalPay;
public:
    HourlyWorker() {}
    HourlyWorker(float wage, float hours) {
        this->wage = wage ;
        this->hours = hours ;
    }
    void calculte () {
        if (hours>40)
        {
            float extraHours = hours - 40;
            float pay1 = extraHours * 1.5 * wage ;
            float pay2 = 40 * wage ;
            totalPay = pay2 + pay1 ;
        }
        else
        {
            totalPay = hours * wage ;
        }
    }
    void getWage()
    {
        cout << "The total Earning is: " << totalPay << endl ;
    }
};
void function(Employee* ptr2);
void main() {
    Employee* ptr1;
    Employee* ptr2;
    cout << "What type of Employee is it: " ;
    cout << "1) Piecewise worker\n2) Hourly Worker\0";
    int option;
    cin >> option;
    switch (option)
    {
    case 1:

        cout << "What is the number of pieces made: " ;
        int pieces;
        cin >> pieces;
        cout << "What is the wage per piece: " ;
        float wage;
        cin >> wage ;
        ptr1 = new PieceWorker(wage,pieces);
        ptr1->setName();
        ptr1->setType();
        ptr1->calculate();
        cout << "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~" << endl ;
        ptr1->getName();
        ptr1->getType();
        ptr1->getWage();

        delete [] ptr1 ;
        break;
    case 2:

        function(ptr2);

        break;
    };
    system("pause"); }
void function(Employee* ptr2)
{

    ptr2 = new HourlyWorker();//this is where the error is occuring


}
```

Comment: Check the spelling of all functions you override. And I also suggest adding the [`override` specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) for all functions you override.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look at our [intro section](https://stackoverflow.com/help), with special attention to the page on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This is not just to make our job easier, it is a vital coding skill, and in this case it would have shown you that your problem is caused by a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You have spelling error - `calculte`. to avoid this, use override keyword, then compiler would warn you about   mismatches.

```
 void calculate () override {
```

Your main function returns `void` while it should return `int`.